# How to rotate (clockwise or anti clockwise) points by specific angle in 3D space along Z direction if center of gravity is known?

Tags: python-3.x, math, linear-algebra

I have points in 3D space and I have found the center of gravity (CG) and I want to rotate those points by some angle(suppose 30 degrees) along the vector passing through CG and parallel to the Z axis.

I have found the CG and defined axis passing through that CG parallel to the Z axis. The code segment that I found on some blog is as shown below but I have modified a little bit.

```
def rotation_matrix(angle, direction, point):
    """Return matrix to rotate about axis defined by point and direction.
    """
    sina = math.sin(angle)
    cosa = math.cos(angle)
    direction = unit_vector(direction[:3])
    # rotation matrix around unit vector
    R = numpy.diag([cosa, cosa, cosa])
    R += numpy.outer(direction, direction) * (1.0 - cosa)
    direction *= sina
    R += numpy.array([[ 0.0,         -direction[2],  direction[1]],
                      [ direction[2], 0.0,          -direction[0]],
                      [-direction[1], direction[0],  0.0]])
    M = numpy.identity(4)
    M[:3, :3] = R
    if point is not None:
        # rotation not around origin
        point = numpy.array(point[:3], dtype=numpy.float64, copy=False)
        M[:3, 3] = point - numpy.dot(R, point)
    return M
```

The actual results are not rotating the points as I am expecting. My vector along which I want to rotate is perpendicular to XY plane and parallel to Z axis. This code is rotating the points in some other direction I am not able to figure out that.

The CG for the data is ::

```
cg = 0.5631200, 0.6244500, 0.0852599
```

The vector defined is as follows:

```
v_tail = np.array([x_c, y_c, 0.0])
v_head = np.array([x_c, y_c, z_c])
v = v_head - v_tail

vector v = [0.      0.      0.08526]
```

and the x, y, z coordinates of the points that I'm trying to rotate is as follows::

```
        x       y      z
0   0.59046 0.62928 0.07307
1   0.59021 0.62943 0.07376
2   0.58970 0.62961 0.07333
3   0.58997 0.62907 0.07220
4   0.59081 0.62902 0.07266
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your code fragment tries to implement [Rodrigues' rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula) but with some errors (I am not so familiar with numpy to discover mistakes)

But for given case, there is simpler way:
To make rotation matrix about such axis, you need the next steps:

```
-matrix of translation by (-cg.x, -cg.y, 0)  T
-matrix of rotation around z-axis by angle   R
-matrix of backward translation by (cg.x, cg.y, 0)  BT
```

Resulting matrix is

```
M = T * R * BT
```

Comment: Let me try this approach.